# The React.js app sends multiple POST requests instead of a single request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing React.js user interface that sends requests to the Django backend. The problem is that the React.js app sends **multiple** requests to the backend on a button click event and page reload event.

But I want to send just a single request when a button `Predict` is clicked in `BottomControls.js`. What is wrong in my code?

**BatchFlights.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import TopControls from "./layout/batch/TopControls"
import MainContent from "./layout/batch/MainContent"
import BottomControls from "./layout/batch/BottomControls"
import styles from "./layout/styles/styles";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

class BatchFlights extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          csvData: [],
          holdingTime: 0,
          prediction: 0,
          labelWidth: 0
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
  };

  updateDelay(prediction) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      prediction: prediction

    }));
  };

  setCsvData = csvData => {
    this.setState({
      csvData
    }, () => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(csvData))
    });
  }

  fetchData = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/batch_predict", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/jsonp, text/plain, */*',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" // otherwise $_POST is empty
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          holdingTime: this.state.holdingTime,
          csvData: this.state.csvData
        })
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.updateDelay(data.prediction)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
      })
  };

  handleChange = (name, event) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value
    }, () => {
      console.log("plannedDep",this.state.plannedDep)
    });
  };


  handleReset = () => {
      this.setState({
          prediction: 0
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (

        <Fragment>

            <TopControls state={this.state} styles={this.props.classes} handleChange={this.handleChange} />

            <MainContent state={this.state} styles={this.props.classes} setCsvData={this.setCsvData} />

            <BottomControls state={this.state} styles={this.props.classes} fetchData={this.fetchData} handleReset={this.handleReset}/>

        </Fragment>

    );
  }
}

const StyledBatchFlights = withStyles(styles)(BatchFlights);
export default StyledBatchFlights;
```

**CSVDataTable.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from 'react-csv-to-table';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const sampleData = `
NUM,AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO,WAKE,SIBT,SOBT,PLANNED_TURNAROUND,DISTANCE_FROM_ORIGIN,DISTANCE_TO_TARGET
1,VLG,M,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,45,2000,2000
2,VLG,M,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,45,2000,2000
`;

class CSVDataTable extends Component {

    state={
      csvData: sampleData
    };

    handleFiles = files => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload =  (e) => {
          // Use reader.result
          this.setState({
            csvData: reader.result
          })
          this.props.setCsvData(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsText(files[0]);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
          <ReactFileReader
            multipleFiles={false}
            fileTypes={[".csv"]}
            handleFiles={this.handleFiles}>
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
            >
                Load data
            </Button>

          </ReactFileReader>
          <CsvToHtmlTable
            data={this.state.csvData || sampleData}
            csvDelimiter=","
            tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"
          />
    </div>
    }
}

export default CSVDataTable;
```

**BottomControls.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

class BottomControls extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
              <CssBaseline />
                <AppBar position="fixed" color="primary" className={this.props.styles.appBar}>
                    <div className={this.props.styles.toolbar}>
                        <Grid container spacing={24}>
                            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.props.fetchData} className={this.props.styles.button}>
                                    Predict
                                    <Icon className={this.props.styles.rightIcon}>send</Icon>
                                </Button>
                                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.props.handleReset} className={this.props.styles.button}>
                                    Reset
                                    <Icon className={this.props.styles.rightIcon}>clear</Icon>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={6} sm={2}>
                                <Card className={this.props.styles.predictedDelay}>
                                    <CardActionArea>
                                        <CardContent>
                                            <div className={this.props.styles.predictedDelayText}>
                                                Prediction: {this.props.state.prediction} <span> </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </CardContent>
                                    </CardActionArea>
                                </Card>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
              </AppBar>
          </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default BottomControls;
```

Comment: Can you create a simple case over https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: you are passing state to `BottomControls ` as props and that state gets updated on fetchData success. any reason to pass state?

Comment: @Jorjon: Hmm, I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @kanhaishah: Yes, I use `this.props.state.prediction` in `BottomControls`.

Comment: @kanhaishah: In my real code I have 10 parameters instead of only `prediction`. Therefore I pass `state={this.state}` to `BottomControls`.

Comment: I just deleted `componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
  };`, and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because your binding an arrow function, this.handleChange, but I don't see any problem besides that

Comment: ReactJs sends a request on page reload and on a button click. I only want to send the request on a button click. I assume that this is related to `componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
  };`

Comment: Maybe is because for some other reason the component is rerendering, I would try to remove that lifecycle method and see if this is the reason

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
};
```

Now the request is sent only on a button click. It is not sent on a page reload.